# Confusion over defining recipients for generic DocuSign templates

Tags: docusignapi

I have an embedded signing application where users going through a web interview have to sign certain documents at the end. The documents are generic templates, currently defined with the user name and email address left blank. I am providing the user name, email address and a clientUserId in the envelope creation, matching the role that is defined in the template. But I keep getting the error UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT - The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope. What constitutes a "valid recipient" of a generic template?  Am I supposed put something in the user and email fields of the template?  I'm confused.

In answer to Larry K below, that appears to be exactly what I have done.  Here's the JSON for the create envelope request that results in the error:

```
{
    "accountId":"1234567",
    "emailSubject":"Certification Documents",
    "status":"sent",
    "compositeTemplates":[
        {
            "serverTemplates":[
                {
                    "sequence":"1",
                    "templateId":"5ed3d600-5a57-4fee-931f-53233858dc65"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates":[
                {
                    "sequence":"1",
                    "recipients":{  
                        "signers":[
                            {
                                "name":"John Doe",
                                "roleName":"Applicant",
                                "recipientId":"1",
                                "clientUserId":"62",
                                "email":"jd@mydomain.com",
                                "tabs":{
                                    "textTabs":[
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel":"EmplName",
                                            "value":"John Doe"
                                        },{
                                            "tabLabel":"SSN",
                                            "value":"123456789"
                                        },{
                                            "tabLabel":"DoB",
                                            "value":"08\/26\/1991"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the Get Recipients response:

```
{ 
    "signers": [ 
        { 
            "isBulkRecipient": "false", 
            "name": "", 
            "email": "", 
            "recipientId": "63543029", 
            "recipientIdGuid": "29a731f6-2f82-490f-9589-f551727414d9",

            "requireIdLookup": "false", 
            "smsAuthentication": {}, 
            "routingOrder": "1", 
            "note": "", 
            "roleName": "Applicant", 
            "status": "created", 
            "declinedReason": "", 
            "deliveryMethod": "email", 
            "templateLocked": "false", 
            "templateRequired": "false" 
        } 
    ], 
    "agents": [], 
    "editors": [], 
    "intermediaries": [], 
    "carbonCopies": [ 
        { 
            "name": "Real Person", 

            "email": "rp@mydomain.com", 
            "recipientId": "83856197", 
            "recipientIdGuid": 
            "0f80a5ab-2050-472a-b072-7a18794a4726", 
            "requireIdLookup": "false", 
            "smsAuthentication": {}, 

            "routingOrder": "1", 
            "note": "", 
            "roleName": "Mancon", 
            "status": "created", 
            "declinedReason": "" 
        } 
    ], 
    "certifiedDeliveries": [], 
    "inPersonSigners": [], 
    "recipientCount": "2" 

}
```

I've got it. Too many iterations of messing with code, mixing live code with debug stuff.  It looked like the error was coming from the envelope creation because I had stepped on a debug message. But in fact the code was going through to the signing view request, which actually was generating the error. And there, as you might guess, was a debug clientUserId, which did not match the envelope. I hate it!  Thanks for the coaching.  It eventually led me to the real problem.

Comment: Can you also try executing a "Get Template Recipients" request (for the same template Id:  5ed3d600-5a57-4fee-931f-53233858dc65) -- GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients -- and update your post with the response.  The error you're receiving indicates a mismatch in recipient info between what you're specifying in the Create Envelope request and how recipient roles are defined in the Template -- seeing the two things side-by-side should allow us to spot the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer from a second DocuSign consultant:

He suggests that perhaps the reason you received the error was that you didn't use the exact same triplet of {recipient/signer name, email, client id} in both your call to Envelopes: create and to EnvelopeViews: createRecipient

The following should work:

Call to Envelopes: create:

```
{
    "emailSubject":"My subject",
    "emailBlurb":"My blurb",
    "templateId":"My template id",
    "templateRoles":[
        {
            "clientUserId":"123456789",
            "roleName":"My role",
            "name":"Name",
            "email":"email"
        }
    ],
    "status":"sent"
}
```

Call to EnvelopeViews: createRecipient:

```
{
    "authenticationMethod": "password",
    "email": "email",
    "returnUrl": "https://www.docusign.com",
    "userName": "Name",
    "clientUserId": "123456789"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot, I'd suggest executing a **Get Template Recipients** request for the Template you're using (`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients`), then compare the contents of that response with the recipients portion of your **Create Envelope From Template** request that's resulting in the error *UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT*. If you can't spot a difference, feel free to update your post (question above) with the trace of your original **Create Envelope** request as well as the response from **Get Template Recipients** (removing any sensitive info, of course), and perhaps someone here can spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A solution from one of our DocuSign consultants is below. He recommends compositing the recipient information with the template. Here's the json for the Envelopes: create call:

```
{
"emailSubject": "Create Envelope with embedded recipient",
"status": "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "{Template ID}"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "2",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "clientUserId": "Unique Identifier",
                            "email": "signer1@example.com",
                            "name": "Signer One",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Customer"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```